# how to update editor content from metabox

Tags: metabox, editor, wp-update-post

hello am trying to update and add editor content from metabox not using the default editor so i tried to use

> wp_update_post($array);

but doesn't work it cause issue

> Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100'

so is there anyway to add or update post content from metabox without using the default editor

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer
i just add

> global $wpdb;

then update the database

```
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` SET 
        `post_content` = '".current_time("Y-m-d H:i:s")."'
         WHERE `ID` = '".$_POST['content']."'" );
```